# Input data dimension problem in CNN with mnist dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm trying to code a model like Lenet to classify images from `mnist` dataset. I define the shape of input layer by `X = Input(shape = (28, 28, 1))`. Then I get an error

```
ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (60000, 28, 28))
```

If I change to `X = Input(shape = (28, 28))`, then I get an error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_12 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 28, 28]
```

Could you please elaborate on where my code got wrong? Thank you so much for your help!

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Input
from keras.utils import to_categorical

######### Lenet-like model
class Lenet_like:
    """
    Lenet like architecture.
    """
    def __init__(self, width, depth, drop, n_classes):
        """
        Architecture settings.

        Arguments:
          - width: int, first layer number of convolution filters.
          - depth: int, number of convolution layer in the network.
          - drop: float, dropout rate.
          - n_classes: int, number of classes in the dataset.
        """
        self.width = width
        self.depth = depth
        self.drop = drop
        self.n_classes = n_classes

    def __call__(self, X):
        """
        Call classifier layers on the inputs.
        """

        for k in range(self.depth):
            # Apply successive convolutions to the input !
            # Use the functional API to do so
            X = Conv2D(filters = self.width / (2 ** k), kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu')(X)
            X = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'valid')(X)
            X = Dropout(self.drop)(X)
            
        # Define the first fully-connected (or dense) layer
        X = Flatten()(X)
        Y = Dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu')(X)

        # Perceptron
        # This is the classification head of the classifier
        X = Flatten()(X)
        Y = Dense(units = self.n_classes, activation = 'softmax')(X)

        return Y
########

def fit_model_on(epochs = 10, batch_size = 32, n_classes = 10):

    # create your model
    X = Input(shape = (28, 28))
    Y = Lenet_like(width = 32, depth = 2, drop = 0.25, n_classes = 10)(X)
    model = Model(X, Y)
    
    # Remember I wanna monitor accuracy
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    # create a Keras ImageDataGenerator to handle your dataset
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = True)
    
    # Load dataset
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
  
    # Convert class vectors to binary class matrices (one-hot encoding).
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, n_classes)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, n_classes)

    # Be sure that your training/test data is 'float32' and between 0 and 1
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.0

    history = model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size), epochs = epochs, validation_data = (x_test, y_test))
    
fit_model_on()
```

Comment: Try to reshape them like: `x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)` and keep input as: `X = Input(shape = (28, 28, 1))`

Comment: @Frightera Because I define the function for 3 datasets `cifar10`, `fashion_mnist`, and `mnist`. For `cifar10`, I use `X = Input(shape = (32, 32, 3))` and it works. Is there any modification that does not required reshape the dataset?

Comment: @Frightera Is there any way to modify `X = Input(shape = (28, 28, 1))` and not to reshape the dataset?

Comment: `mnist` training set is loaded as `60000, 28,28`, `cifar10` loaded as `50000, 32,32,3`. Since `mnist` is grayscale you should reshape it. You need to reshape to match the expected dimensions of 2D Convolution.